# Android java: OutOfMemory while inserting a huge List into the database SQL

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, out-of-memory, greendao

I'm just working on an Android Project where an ORM greendao is used. It allows me to insert a number of entities (which are obviously objects) into the database at once (in one transaction). In practice there's a method

insertOrReplaceInTx(...)

which takes as a parameter a collection, given a List of objects. The problem is that my list has sort of 12000 objects and an insert leads from time to time to an OutOfMemory Exception. I'm thinking of a smart way to solve the problem and prevent future OOM. The only idea which comes to my mind is to split the huge collection into sort of subcollections (let's say 500 elements each) and commit in a loop making several small commits instead of one huge. The bad thing about it is that it takes longer to insert the records and time matters here. In the end I'm not sure if making commit after commit doesn't kill the heap anyway. Maybe call a sleep() method in between to let GC clear the heap ...but it looks to me as a kind of ugly solution.

any smart ideas on your side?
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you get the error when you try to insert the data? Cause If your data is already in memory when you try to insert it, I can't think of any reason for an out of memory exception there.

Comment: yes it's the last method on my side (before greendao ORM comes into play). I suppose the greendao does some magic things and creates new objects while building an insert. Here're the methods which get called after calling insertOrReplaceInTx()

see my next comment (characters limitation)

Comment: 1  de.greenrobot.dao.internal.LongHashMap.setCapacity  LongHashMap.java, line 130
2  de.greenrobot.dao.internal.LongHashMap.put  LongHashMap.java, line 93
3  de.greenrobot.dao.identityscope.IdentityScopeLong.put2NoLock  IdentityScopeLong.java, line 94
4  de.greenrobot.dao.identityscope.IdentityScopeLong.putNoLock  IdentityScopeLong.java, line 81

(...)

8  de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.executeInsertInTx  AbstractDao.java, line 270
9  de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.insertOrReplaceInTx  AbstractDao.java, line 235
10 de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.insertOrReplaceInTx  AbstractDao.java, line 245

Comment: just found a nice library which makes partitioning of a collection into small ones without additional memory fuss

using this:
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

I ended up with:


  
`for (List<TVShowInt> sublist : Lists.partition(struct, 500)) {
   tvShowIntDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(sublist);
  }`

not much time in the end taken out, but maybe you'll have a better idea. Of course I'm still not sure if mine solves the problem

Comment: @basta Did you solve your problem? If you have any question about my answer feel free to write a comment.

Comment: Hi :) many thanks for your answer, I've built in the solution of AlexS due to some dependencies in my code and I'm gonna make a release then thousands of users will test it properly since I cannot really reproduce this problem on any handset of mine...

Comment: Any progress on your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I am working on a project using greendao 1.3.1. Some of the tables containing about 200000 entities (not containing a lot of properties).

I read the entities from csv and to speed things up I developed a small solution, which might also help with your OOM-issue.

For explanation:

greendao uses a cache and after each insert it updates the entity to get the row-id and probably inserts the entity into its cache. On top of that greendao starts a transaction if you call an insert or an update method and if there isn't already a transaction. This slows down "bulk"-inserts and increases the memory usage and also reduces speed.

---

What I did:

### Performance (time)

To fasten things up I started a transaction before I did any insert. This way greendao will not start a transaction on every insert and all inserts and updates are in the same transaction which has additional benefits concerning data consistency.
You can use code like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dao.getDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();

try {
    // do all your inserts and so on here.
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (Exception ex) {
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

But this won't help you with your OOM-problem yet.

### Memory-usage

**Solution 1**

If you don't want to mess with the greendao-code you can issue a `DaoSession.clear()` every once in a while.
This is definitely the simple solution, but will be less performant than solution 2.

**Solution 2**

To prevent greendao from updateing and inserting the entity into its cache you can replace the method `private long executeInsert(T entity, SQLiteStatement stmt)` with this code in **AbstractDao.java**:

```
/**
 * Insert an entity into the table associated with a concrete DAO.
 * 
 * @return row ID of newly inserted entity
 */
public long insertOrReplace(T entity, boolean update) {
    return executeInsert(entity, statements.getInsertOrReplaceStatement(), update);
}

private long executeInsert(T entity, SQLiteStatement stmt) {
    return executeInsert(entity, stmt, true);
}

private long executeInsert(T entity, SQLiteStatement stmt, boolean update) {
    long rowId;
    if (db.isDbLockedByCurrentThread()) {
        synchronized (stmt) {
            bindValues(stmt, entity);
            rowId = stmt.executeInsert();
        }
    } else {
        // Do TX to acquire a connection before locking the stmt to avoid deadlocks
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            synchronized (stmt) {
                bindValues(stmt, entity);
                rowId = stmt.executeInsert();
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
    if (update) {
        updateKeyAfterInsertAndAttach(entity, rowId, true);
    }
    return rowId;
}
```